# C++ - Different concurrent behavious when using locals and globals

Tags: c++, multithreading, global-variables

Given this program:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
template<typename T>
struct node
{
    T data;
    node* next;
    node(const T& data) : data(data), next(nullptr) {}
};

template<typename T>
class stack {
    std::atomic<node<T>*> head;
 public:
    void push(const T& data) {
      node<T>* new_node = new node<T>(data);
      new_node->next = head.load();
      while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node));
    }
    node<T>* get_head() {
        return head;
    }
};

stack<int> x;
int main() {
    std::cout << "main() starts" << std::endl;
    const int MAKS_OP = 100;
    std::thread t1{[&]{
        for (int i = 0; i < MAKS_OP; ++i) {
            x.push(i); 
            std::string s = "Thread 1 added ";
            s += std::to_string(i);
            s += " to the stack!\n";
            std::cout << s; 
        } 
    }};
    std::thread t2{[&]{
        for (int i = 0; i < MAKS_OP; ++i) {
            x.push(i); 
            std::string s = "Thread 2 added ";
            s += std::to_string(i);
            s += " to the stack!\n";
            std::cout << s;
        }
    }};
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    for (auto nod = x.get_head(); nod != nullptr; nod = nod->next) {
        std::cout << nod->data << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "main() completes\n";
}
```

The code is more or less appropriated from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange).
In its current state it behaves exactly as expected, both threads push numbers to the stack in an unspecified order, and the stack is then printed in the correct order. It works whether or not I specify the default lambda capture for threads. However, when I move the declaration of stack x into main(), the program runs into a segfault when printing the contents of the stack. GDB tells me that it happens when accessing `nod->data` in the loop at the end, and running `info locals` crashes gdb. What is going on? Why does it even make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure but, where in your code `head` member is initialized ?
When you create object as global variable (above `main` function) `head` will have 0 value, but when you create your stack object in main function as local variable, head will contain junk data - random value.

About default constructor from cppreference.com

> 1) The default constructor is trivial: no initialization takes place other than zero initialization of static and thread-local objects. std::atomic_init may be used to complete initialization.

Comment: the bug is also in the cppreference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange

i have wasted time on debugging uninitialized atomics and have not seen a compiler warn about it. cppcheck didn't detect it either.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the std::atomic*> head; in the stack constructor as follows, that should solve the issue,

```
    template<typename T>
    class stack {
        std::atomic<node<T>*> head;
    public:
        stack()
        {
          head = 0;
        }
        void push(const T& data) {
          node<T>* new_node = new node<T>(data);
          new_node->next = head.load();
          while (!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node));
        }
        node<T>* get_head() {
          return head;
        }
    };
```